# Creating a function that would execute a different function a certain number of times

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def loop(count, cmd):
    for i in range(count):
        cmd
```

I'd call the function like this: `loop(4, print("Send nudes"))`
and then the function would be executed 4 times e.i. the string "send nudes" would appear in the console 4 times.
How can I structure my function so this would work?

Comment: `"print("Send nudes")"`? What are you using this code for?

Comment: What you have looks fine, just remember to actually call the function: `cmd()` not just `cmd`

Comment: it's an example but mostly for calling functions I defined formerly multiple times with just with one line of code

Comment: @RobinZigmond What OP has is not fine. Try it yourself, the interpreter will tell you that `None` is not callable.

Comment: @mypetlion- oh yeah, you're right, I read too quickly. I assumed that `cmd` was a function taking no arguments. You could still make it work though, I guess, by passing the parameters as the third argument to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code:

```
loop(4, print("Send nudes"))
```

You're not passing in the function itself. You're passing in the result of having called that function. Which in the case of `print` will be `None`. For what you'd want, probably the easiest way would be to wrap the function call in a `lambda` expression, and then call that lambda. Try this:

```
def loop(count, cmd):
    for i in range(count):
        cmd()
loop(4, lambda: print("Send nudes"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass functions as objects to other functions.

```
def loop(count, cmd, *cmd_args):
    for i in range(count):
        cmd(*cmd_args)

loop(4, print, "send stuff")
```

Note that you should not "call" your function, but just pass it as is. Calling the function replaces the call with the return value (which is None for print)

EDITlog: changing cmd_args to *cmd_args for better functionality

Comment: while mypetlion's answer is more pythonic. I also upvoted this because it shows a different approach that can be relevant in the right context. I will however edit the `cmd_args` to `*cmd_args` to accommodate for multiple arguments

Comment: Agreed, it makes the toy example here more robust to multiple arguments.